# jQuery toggle menu is slipping

Tags: drop-down-menu, jquery

I have a menu: http://jsfiddle.net/paTNz/2/

If you catch one or two pixels directly under the word "English", the menu slams back shut. I can't understand since the event is bound to the outer `li` item which covers everything inside it: the "English" href and the sub menu.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: I have 2 questions. 1) Why use `e.preventDefault();` before toggle? 2) Why you use hover? These days ppl use a lot of touch-screens so your application wont work perfectly.

Comment: just a hangover, it was originally click, changed to test. back to what it shudve been: http://jsfiddle.net/paTNz/7/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thats just because there is a few pixels of space between your menus.

Easy fix just add some padding to your a link to take up the space,

http://jsfiddle.net/paTNz/3/

```
.info li.lang a {padding-bottom:3px}
```

Comment: I guess a better answer is the ul inside your li is absolute positioning, so the li will not contain the element and the a link is the only element the li constrains to. Which is why we need the padding to bridge the gap between the 2 menus. If that makes sense.